# How to check if array column is inside another column array in PySpark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have the following case

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([  # schema
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ev", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("ev2", ArrayType(StringType()), True),])
df = spark.createDataFrame([{"id": "se1", "ev": ["ev11", "ev12"], "ev2": ["ev11"]},
                            {"id": "se2", "ev": ["ev11"], "ev2": ["ev11", "ev12"]},
                            {"id": "se3", "ev": ["ev21"], "ev2": ["ev11", "ev12"]},
                            {"id": "se4", "ev": ["ev21", "ev22"], "ev2": ["ev21", "ev22"]}],
                           schema=schema)
```

Which gives me:

```
df.show()
+---+------------+------------+
| id|          ev|         ev2|
+---+------------+------------+
|se1|[ev11, ev12]|      [ev11]|
|se2|      [ev11]|[ev11, ev12]|
|se3|      [ev21]|[ev11, ev12]|
|se4|[ev21, ev22]|[ev21, ev22]|
+---+------------+------------+
```

I want to create a new column of boolean (or select only the true cases) for the rows where the contents of the "ev" column are inside the "ev2" column, returning:

```
df_target.show()
```

```
+---+------------+------------+
| id|          ev|         ev2|
+---+------------+------------+
|se2|      [ev11]|[ev11, ev12]|
|se4|[ev21, ev22]|[ev21, ev22]|
+---+------------+------------+
```

or:

```py
df_target.show()
```

```
+---+------------+------------+-------+
| id|          ev|         ev2|evInEv2|
+---+------------+------------+-------+
|se1|[ev11, ev12]|      [ev11]|  false|
|se2|      [ev11]|[ev11, ev12]|   true|
|se3|      [ev21]|[ev11, ev12]|  false|
|se4|[ev21, ev22]|[ev21, ev22]|   true|
+---+------------+------------+-------+
```

I tried using the `isin` method:

```py
df.withColumn('evInEv2', df['ev'].isin(df['ev2'])).show()
```

```
+---+------------+------------+-------+
| id|          ev|         ev2|evInEv2|
+---+------------+------------+-------+
|se1|[ev11, ev12]|      [ev11]|  false|
|se2|      [ev11]|[ev11, ev12]|  false|
|se3|      [ev21]|[ev11, ev12]|  false|
|se4|[ev21, ev22]|[ev21, ev22]|   true|
+---+------------+------------+-------+
```

But it looks like it only checks if it's the same array.

I also tried the `array_contains` function from `pyspark.sql.functions` but only accepts one object and not an array to check.

I am having difficulties even searching for this due to phrasing the correct problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an option using a `udf`, where we check the length of the difference between the columns `ev` and `ev2`. When the length of the resulting array is `0` , or all elements of `ev` are contained within `ev2`, we return `True`; otherwise `False`.

```py
def contains(x,y):
  z = len(set(x) - set(y))
  if z == 0:
    return True
  else:
    return False

contains_udf = udf(contains)
df.withColumn("evInEv2", contains_udf(df.ev,df.ev2)).show()
+---+------------+------------+-------+
| id|          ev|         ev2|evInEv2|
+---+------------+------------+-------+
|se1|[ev11, ev12]|      [ev11]|  false|
|se2|      [ev11]|[ev11, ev12]|   true|
|se3|      [ev21]|[ev11, ev12]|  false|
|se4|[ev21, ev22]|[ev21, ev22]|   true|
+---+------------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I didn't even think about using udfs

Answer (score 11):

One more implementation for **Spark >= 2.4.0** avoiding UDF and using the built-in `array_except`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import size, array_except

def is_subset(a, b):
  return size(array_except(a, b)) == 0
  
df.withColumn("is_subset", is_subset(df.ev, df.ev2))
```

Output:

```
+---+------------+------------+---------+
| id|          ev|         ev2|is_subset|
+---+------------+------------+---------+
|se1|[ev11, ev12]|      [ev11]|    false|
|se2|      [ev11]|[ev11, ev12]|     true|
|se3|      [ev21]|[ev11, ev12]|    false|
|se4|[ev21, ev22]|[ev21, ev22]|     true|
+---+------------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Better option then creating UDF

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use

```
subsetOf=udf(lambda A,B: set(A).issubset(set(B)))
df.withColumn("evInEv2", subsetOf(df.ev,df.ev2)).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Spark UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
antecedent_inside_predictions = udf(lambda antecedent,prediction: all(elem in prediction for elem in antecedent), BooleanType())
```

and then use it in a join as so:

```
fp_predictions =  filtered_rules.join(personal_item_recos,antecedent_inside_predictions("antecedent", "item_predictions") )
```

Note that I needed to enable crossJoins:

```
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled', True)
```

(Finally, I extract the particular item I want from the item as follows:

```
fp_predictions = fp_predictions.withColumn("ITEM_SK", fp_predictions.consequent.getItem(0))
```